# How to find a substring of a double-quoted string with a dollar sign in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, find

I wanted to correct the automatically created Linux scripts. I use `findAll(String, String)` function to change `"$APP_ARGS"` for something else.

I have tried variants:

```
replaceAll('"$APP_ARGS"', 'simulators ' + '"\\\\$APP_ARGS"')    - doesn't find
replaceAll('\"\$APP_ARGS\"',...    - doesn't find
replaceAll('"\$APP_ARGS"',...    - doesn't find
replaceAll('\\"\\$APP_ARGS\\"',...    - editor warning - excessive escape
replaceAll('"\\\\$APP_ARGS"',...    - doesn't find
replaceAll('\\\\"\\\\$APP_ARGS\\\\"',...    - doesn't find
replaceAll($/"$$APP_ARGS"/$, ...)   - does not find
replaceAll('"[$]APP_ARGS"', 'something simple')       - finds.
replaceAll('"[$]APP_ARGS"', '"\\\\$APP_ARGS"')       - fails.
```

As you see, if I use the regex format, the finding works ok. But is there a way to make an escaping work? For I need that `$` in the replacing string, too.

According to Groovy manuals, /../ string needn't escaping for anything except slashes themselves. But

```
 replaceAll(/"$APP_ARGS"/,...
```

fails, too, with a message:  Could not get unknown property 'APP_ARGS'.

It seems that behaviour of that function has no logic and we have to find the correct solution by experiments.

Comment: You are battling GStrings and RegExp at once. If you use just `replace` you can use single-quoted strings and don't have to deal with quoting in the regexp.  e.g. `'ls $ARGS'.replace('$ARGS', "-l")`

Comment: I believed you if not the same problem with the second parameter, that is a pure String. And the first parameter, BTW, is the String type, too, not Pattern. That is what I am talking about: the first parameter is declared as String, but works as Pattern - partly. No logic.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the second argument, unless you are trying something, that is not clear in your question to me. try `'ls "$ARGS"'.replace('"$ARGS"', '-l "$ARGS"')` and if that is not what you expect, please elaborate. `replaceAll` wants a regexp as first param (and will turn your string into one).

Comment: @cfrick you have explained all as an edition to my answer. Thank you. But I think it would be fairer to put your edition + a pair of examples as a separate answer and I would gladly mark it as the correct answer... But I insist that having a function with String arguments that are read as Pattern arguments is extremely illogical. The types of arguments of replaceAll should be Pattern.... And that makes your correct answer really a great feat!

Comment: your answer is correct - i just wanted to add the "why".  don't bother.  also `String.replaceAll` is from the JDK itself - so not groovys fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
replaceAll('"\\$APP_ARGS"', 'simulators ' + '"\\$APP_ARGS"')
```

The additional possible problem is that `\\` before `$` should be in the both strings, replacing and replaced.

The first argument of `replaceAll` is always treated as an regexp, so we need to quote `$` (line end).  The second param may contain backreferences to groups from the regexp, which start with a `$`, so that one must be quoted too.

A saner way is to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, which already quotes/escapes both params according to that useage.