# What are the correct rules for Groovy escaping?

Tags: string, groovy, escaping

In the [Groovy manual](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/) you can found these two pieces of text:

> Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals,
> apart from single and triple single quoted strings.
>
> Slashy string
> ...
> Only forward slashes need to be escaped with a backslash

They are obviously contradictory, for, according to the second sentence, /$a/ will be interpreted as '`$a`'. But, according to the first one, it will be interpreted as '`-the meaning of variable a-`'. In the real life, it will work the second way.

What is interesting, the dollar before something that looks like a variable should be escaped in single-quoted strings, too. Real life examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42347332/715269). Groovy tries to read $ as a variable name prefix even when not interpolating.

It seems, the explanation of the dollar slashy strings sets it correctly for ALL strings:

> except to escape the dollar of a string subsequence that would start
> like a GString placeholder sequence, ...

Could you formulate the correct and uncontradictory rules for groovy escape rules?

---

*The practical tests were made on Gradle plugin for Intellij.*

Comment: There is a very nice writeup of this in Groovy In Action pp.70-73. I don't want to paste it here though, it's not mine to share. You may be able to read it under free preview ion Manning's [site](https://livebook.manning.com/book/groovy-in-action-second-edition/chapter-3/158)